# create new java class in spring application

Tags: java, spring, maven, vaadin

this is my first spring application (maven project) which is supposed to allow users to upload and validate a file. At the moment I only have the default class called MyUI.java which contains all I need, here is an extract:

EDITED CODE:

FileUploader.java

`public class FileUploader extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent {

        public void callScript(){//as usual, it needs a method!!
            JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(""

                    +"jsInit();"
                +"");

        }`

And changes to the MyUI class:
`final FileUploader fileUploader = new FileUploader();//has to be final apparently

```
   final Button button = new Button("Open popup");
    button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event){
            fileUploader.callScript();
        } 
    });`
```

I need to move the js call to a new java class in a separate file, so I created a new class which now sits in its own file and that will extend AbstractJavaScriptComponent, my question is, what imports do I need for this class, all the ones that are in the previous class except for the UI or including those? Literally this class will only have the js call for now (there will be more stuff later)?
Also, to make use of this class presumably I will have to run As --> maven install again? And in general, what should I do?
cheers

Comment: Which imports? Just remove all the imports, let your IDE of choice show the compile errors, then import them from the suggestions

Comment: OK, thanks @cricket_007 so far my new class looks like this http://pastebin.com/WQaGN8YY and my old one is this http://pastebin.com/dKYSri1W
What do I need to do in order for the application to call the javascript file as in the new class? At the moment I I get java errors:
`-Syntax error on token ".", { expected
-Syntax error on token "getcurrent", identifier expected after this token
-Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody`
Do I somehow, in the old class, create an object of the new class? Sorry I've never done this before

Comment: You've never used spring or you've never made a Java class because that's a syntax error, and should be simple to figure out with any IDE (I use Intellij, for example)

Comment: That first link has no methods. That's most likely your first problem

Comment: That was indeed my first problem. The application compiles but since I've moved things around my javascript function doesn't get called. My old class MyUI defines a button and adds a class to it, which is all good. The second class, the new one, here is it now http://pastebin.com/Xu9JwVTZ includes the script.js (and this works OK) and then calls a jsInit() function, which resides in the script.js file and that, for some reasons, doesn't get called...
`function jsInit(){
 console.log("jsInit() is called");
...
}`

Comment: You are allowed to [edit] your question to include code changes, please try not to use PasteBin. That being said, I don't know what the problem is now, but how do you expect java to know about your javascript file that contains the function you are trying to call?

Comment: OK sorry I will change the code next time. When I was calling the js function from the MyUI.java class, it all worked OK, I could call it with a simple javascript function call as per my code above, but since I moved the call to my new class, it doesn't work, so I thought it had to have something to do with the new class as opposed to java knowing about that function. Also, as the function call sits inside a `JavaScript.getCurrent().execute` I would have thought it'd execute anyway as it did before

Comment: I'm not really sure I see what you're trying to do, honestly. You should be using Java and the framework to accept some `File` object. Where does executing Javascript on the server-side fit into that process?

Comment: Well, as I'm more comfortable with JS, I started with it but in future I will refactor this and use java components. For now, it's JS I'm afraid. What bugs me is that it worked before when it was in the MyUI class but not anymore now...

Comment: Okay, I've just never really see this Vaadin library before. Do you ever call `new FileUploader()` followed by calling that method you defined? I don't see why that doesn't work.

Comment: No, I don't actually. Told you that I'm still learning, spring, java etc etc... Anyway, new FIleUploader should then be called in MyUI.java of course, but do I have to reference the FileUploader class in any other way in addition to `new FIleUploader()`?

Comment: OK got it, I added it inside MyUI.java:
`final FileUploader fileUploader = new FileUploader();
fileUploader.callScript();`
Now I have another problem, but hopefully I will sort that too. Basically with the above addition the js function gets called all the time as soon as the app starts, wherease it needs to be called on click, so I'll add the function call inside the click handler for the button and that means that I have to sort out the JS end as well, otherwise I will end up with two clicks to run the function. WIll post back. In the meanwhile, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple case of [refactoring to extract a method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) and add a class.

You want to replace this

```
final Button button = new Button("Open popup");
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("jsInit();");
```

With something like this

```
final Button button = new Button("Open popup");
JavaScriptCaller jsCaller = new JavaScriptCaller(JavaScript.getCurrent());
jsCaller.jsInit();
```

So, you can define a class like so

```
public class JavaScriptCaller extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent {
    final JavaScript js;

    public JavaScriptCaller(JavaScript js) {
        this.js = js;
    }

    public void jsInit() {
        this.js.execute("jsInit();")
    }
}
```

The reason I added the parameter is so you don't need to keep calling the `Javascript.getCurrent()` since you only need one instance of it.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the code at the top to show you my solution, which probably isn't as effective as yours, but still, it works:
I created a FileUploader object in my MyUI class and called the method that calls the js function from within the click handler